# Is it possible to use dnsmasq to map example.local to IP:port?

Tags: dns, tomato, dnsmasq

I'm using a Linksys WRT54GL running the Victek Mod Tomato 1.25 firmware. It has support for dnsmasq. I also have a local server running on a certain IP and port.

How can I map an internal domain name (example.local) to an IP:port?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [SRV record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record). But your client software must have support for reading and using the SRV record.